# How to pass more parameters to spring validate method

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have extension of org.springframework.validation.Validator.

```
public class MyValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
        public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        ...
    }
}
```

My goal is to pass more than one target to method.

I don't like idea with overload `validate` method because it smells as bad code:
`validate(Object target1, Object target1, Errors errors)` or creating map with needed targets.

It will be good to know better approach regarding this case.

Comment: would you please clarify what is your goal? do you need to validate some object that depends on the different one or there is something else?

Comment: So, in general I have controller which recieve two parameters "String and List<String>. The first one is id that shoud be validated, the another one is list of old ids. First of all I should validate size of  list, then should validate id and add it to general list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use a target bean which holds all the data which need to be validated. Something like

```
private static final class ParamsBean {
  String id;
  List<String> oldIds;
}
```

Then we simply cast the object. It's the cleanest possible solution imo, as it does not use generic `Map` or `List` of unknown objects (though the casting still is not nice).

Comment: @kenor, could you give more details about how to pass this ParammsBean object into the validator? I have a similar question with my code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387869/how-to-wrap-the-entity-data-and-pass-to-the-spring-validator. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

I did not try the following code, but it demonstrates a basic idea how one field of the bean could be verified against the other. Hopefully, it will help you

Let's say you have the following form bean

```
public class MyForm {
    private String id;
    private List<String> oldIds;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<String> getOldIds() {
        return oldIds;
    }

    public void setOldIds(List<String> oldIds) {
        this.oldIds = oldIds;
    }

}
```

and the id property has to be validated against the oldIds object (if i did understand your requirements correctly). To achieve it your need to create a constraint and mark your bean. So, the first is the constraint interface

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyConstraintValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface MyConstraint {

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    String[] value();
}
```

next, you need to implement the constraint validator class:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils;

public class MyConstraintValidator implements
    ConstraintValidator<MyConstraint, Object> {

    private String firstAttribute;
    private String secondAttribute;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final MyConstraint constraintAnnotation) {
        firstAttribute = constraintAnnotation.value()[0];
        secondAttribute = constraintAnnotation.value()[1];

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Object object,
            final ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {
        try {
            final String id = (String) PropertyUtils.getProperty(object,
                    firstAttribute);
            List<String> oldIds = (List<String>) PropertyUtils.getProperty(
                    object, secondAttribute);

            // do your validation

            return true;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

finally, apply the created constraint to the form bean

```
@MyConstraint(value = { "id", "oldIds" })
public class MyForm {
    // the code
}
```

For now, your mark your bean with the @Valid annotation from the javax.validation package or feed it to the validator object

Answer (score 0):

i faced with a similar situation where i need to pass more arguments to the validate method so i came up with a idea of my own.in my case i wanted a String  to be passed to this method

validate method implemented in  the following classes `CustomValidatorBean`, `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`, `OptionalValidatorFactoryBean`, `SpringValidatorAdapter`

I extended the `CustomValidatorBean` and called the validate method in super class and it is working perfectly

```
import javax.validation.Validator;`
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;`
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;`
importorg.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.CustomValidatorBean;`
public class MyValidator extends CustomValidatorBean {`
    public void myvalidate(Object target,Errors errors,String flag,Profile profile)
    {
        super.validate(target,errors);
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(profile.name())){
            errors.rejectValue("name", "NotBlank.profilereg.name", new Object[] { "name" }, "Missing Required Fields");
        }       

    }           

}
```