# How to wrap the entity data and pass to the spring validator

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-validator

I am trying to wrap the entity data with some other information such as requestor info. Right now, I have the following code,

```
public class EntityController {

    @Autowired
    private EntityValidator entityValidator;

    ...

    @InitBinder("entity")
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(entityValidator);
    }

}
```

and my validitor is like

```
public class EntityValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clz) {
        return Entity.class.equals(clz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        ...
    }

}
```

For the Object parameter passed into the validate method is the Entity class object now. As I said, I want a customized object with this entity class object wrapped in. Is that possible? If yes, how to do that? Please help. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the `Entity` instance to be a member of another class (a customized object with this entity class object wrapped in). How about something like this:

```
public interface EntityHolder {
  Entity getEntity();
}
```

Which you can implement (the customized object) in a number of ways:

```
public class RequestorInfo implements EntityHolder {
  private final long requestorId;
  public Entity getEntity() { ... }
}

public class CustomObject2 implements EntityHolder {
  public Entity getEntity() { ... }
}
```

And then use the validator like this:

```
public class EntityValidator implements Validator {

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> clz) {
    return EntityHolder.class.isAssignableFrom(clz);
  }

  @Override
  public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
    EntityHolder holder = (EntityHolder) obj;
    // validate the entity obtained by holder.getEntity()  
  }

}
```

Notice the `equals` was changed to `isAssignableFrom` in the `supports` method. This enables you to pass in a subclass of `EntityHolder`.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I want. However, I have one question. Let's say when I do a post, my controller method is `public Entity create(@Valid @RequestBody Entity entity) {
        return entityService.create(entity);
    }`. And the extra info (requester) I want to wrap is in a Aspect class. Where can I put the wrapping process into? I mean where/how can encapsulate the requester info and entity info together into the wrapper? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I mean, should I wrap them in my aspect class? cause that's where I get the requester info. My aspect class method looks like `public Object handleControllerMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        //get requester info 
        ...... 
        Object obj = null;

        obj = pjp.proceed();

        return obj;
    }`

Comment: Sorry, cannot help here, I have very little experience with AspectJ

Comment: still many thanks. in your case, how do u have the requester passed in? more specifically, in the post method of the controller, whats the argument type? entity or entityholder?

Comment: I would say `RequestorInfo`

Comment: Thank you. Kenor. I guess that's back to the same scenario then. I guess what I want is probably not achievable.